# laravel validate multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I have a page which have a select with `name="action_id[]"`, the user can add another action by clicking on a button. The new action is another select with  `name="action_id[]"` so I end up with a view that has many selects with the same name.

when the user submits the form, I do this in the controller:

```
$actions = Input::get('action_id')
```

and I get an array.

How to validate these values? They have the same name, so I can **not** do this because it validates only one `action_id`:

```
$validation = Validator::make($actions, Actions::rules)
```

where `Actions::rules` is

```
public static $rules = array(
    'action_id' => 'required|integer|not_in:0'
);
```

**How can I validate the array of actions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do it with a `foreach()`:

```
foreach ($actions as $singleAction) {
    $validation = Validator::make($singleAction, Actions::rules);
    // do whatever foo with $validation
}
```

this assumes that your `$actions` is the array returned by the form. It should look like this:

```
array(
    0 => 'action1',
    1 => 'action2',
  // etc
);
```

Comment: I got this exception `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, string given`

Comment: +1 it works now, I will accept when the system allows